# Excel VBA - how to copy data to specific cell in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with data that comes in one workbook but lots of different sheets. The number of sheets can vary.

I want to create a macro that combines all the data into one sheet and then copies the name of the data type onto the top of each set of data.

I have the first part down, but I’m having trouble with copying data and indexing the column. Basically, I am copying a cell from the source book and I want to paste to A1,B1,C1,.......Z1 (or however many unique data points there are).

Is there a way to index over on the columns? Here is the code:

```
Sub ImportData()
   Dim FileLocation As String
   Dim s As Integer
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim finalRow As Integer
   Dim n As Integer
   Dim k As Integer

    
    FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FileLocation = "False" Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation)
    
    s = wb.Sheets.Count
    'MsgBox (s)
    
    
    'Find how many rows of data there are
        
    finalRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox (finalRow)
    
    'import date
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("C3:C" & finalRow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    n = 1
  
    'Import the data from each tab onto 1 sheet
    For n = 1 To s
    wb.Worksheets(n).Range("D3:D" & finalRow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(n + 1)
    'MsgBox (n)
    
    Next n
    
    k = 1
    
    
    'copy column title
     For k = 1 To s
    wb.Worksheets(k).Range("A4").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(k + 1)
    'MsgBox (k)
    
    Next k
   
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Range(Cells(rowindex,columnindex).address,Cells(rowindex,columnindex).address)` to refer to the column by number instead of letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    wb.Worksheets(n).Range("D3:D" & finalRow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,n)
```

' Use Cells(rowNum,colNum) not Columns

Seems you can use one for next instead of two